# python postgresql - cannot be referenced

Tags: python, postgresql

trying to do a basic insert of some values in a table called source...

```
def insert_source():
    sql = """INSERT INTO source(sha1, height, width) VALUES(sha1, height, width) RETURNING id;"""
```

results in:

```
column "sha1" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO source(sha1, height, width) VALUES(sha1, height,...
                                                       ^
HINT:  There is a column named "sha1" in table "source", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
```

UPDATE:
I'm attempting to use variables as the values... need an example of this working.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL statement is not correct, there should be actual values, enclosed by double quotes if needed, in the `VALUES()` statement. A correct query would be:

```sql
INSERT INTO source(sha1, height, width) VALUES("sha1", "height", "width") RETURNING id;
```

**Supposing** all your columns are text, or varchar.

Comment: In the values those are variables that should be filled in....

Comment: No, in `VALUES`, it is values that should be added to a new row, variables that should be filled in go in the parenthesis when naming the edited table

Comment: can you post an actual example using variables?

Comment: See [How to use VALUES](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=01479e3abd4c4a2cd4f912c0cc81d2f3).

Answer (score 0):

Very basic indeed. I suggest checking the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-values.html). It contains several examples. Also See [How to use VALUES](http://%20https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=01479e3abd4c4a2cd4f912c0cc81d2f3). But the basic statement: (Subject to correct data types)

```
insert into source(sha1, height, width) 
      values ('Rectangle', 10, 20);
```